# Validate that EF Core ModelSnapshot, migrations, and actual database schema are consistent with each other

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core. After "cleverly" merging a couple of source control branches that both introduced migrations, I'm no longer confident that my [`ModelSnapshot`](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/model-snapshot) is consistent with either my migrations or my actual database.

Is there some command or function that I can use to validate that the three are consistent with each other (i.e. that the snapshot is a faithful representation of the current database schema and that the migrations, when applied to a newly-created database, will generate that schema)?

Answer (score 3):

Here are tools you can use to perform some sanity checks.

- `Add-Migration` will show any differences between your current model and the model snapshot
- `Script-Migration` will produce a SQL script you can use to create a database from the migrations
- [CreateDatabaseScript](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2943) will produce a SQL script you can use to create a database from the model
- [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh272690.aspx) can compare two databases
- `Scaffold-DbContext` will create a model that is compatible with a database